# Firebase Retrieving Data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from firebase but for some reason it isn't working. I tried numerous things but they still don't seem to work. I am trying to retrieve all the items within the "DailyRemedies" section

Code:

```
ref.child("Users/\(userUID!)").child("DailyRemedies").observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in
    
    if let userDict  = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
        print(userDict["DailyRemedies"]!)
    }
    
}
```

json:

```
{
 "EFy3Ba9sHDZYLazhzXmgqZ5RWJL2" : {
        "DailyRemedies" : [ "not done", "done", "done", "done", "done", "done", "done" ],
        "Email" : "abc@aol.com",
        "Password" : "kalani"
 }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of my firebase]

Comment: What doesn't work?  What's that json - is it what you are hoping to get, or what you are getting?

Comment: well i expected userDict to contain the list of values from "DailyRemedies" from the JSON but it didn't work. I basically want to grab that list of those "done" values | Update: I just included the full json from my database that includes the userUID as well

Comment: You still aren't saying what "didn't/doesn't work" means. You mean that the value was empty? Undefined? A different set of values than you expected? There was a crash? Is the callback function not getting called at all?

Comment: breakpoint was set at the print statement but it didnt hit so im assuming there is a problem with the declaration of the userDict to the snapshot value. userDict comes out empty, so i cant retrieve the data from the "DailyRemedies" part. therefore, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ref.child("Users").child(userUID).child("DailyRemedies").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print(snapshot)
        } else {
            //
        }
    })
```